# Как вывести содержимое переменной в MessageBox?

Tags: c++, строки

У меня есть функция с `MessageBox`.
Мне нужно сделать, чтобы в содержимое `MessageBox` выводилась переменная `a`.

Попытался использовать вот это, но мало того, что переменная не вывелась, так еще и половина текста куда-то пропала:

```
int a = 10;
int DisplayResourceNAMessageBox()
{
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCTSTR)L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again? "+a,
        (LPCTSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1
    );
    return msgboxID;
}

int main()
{
   DisplayResourceNAMessageBox(); 
}
```

P.S. Пример взял с сайта Майкрософта

Comment: Ну, например, [`swprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) к вашим услугам. Или `wstring`, раз уж у вас С++.

Comment: Извините, не могли бы вы дать пример кода, если не трудно?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#define  UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

int a = 10;
int DisplayResourceNAMessageBox()
{
    wchar_t buf[100];
    swprintf(buf,100,L"%s%d",L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again? ",a);
    // Так тоже работает, хотя и выводит предупреждение...
    // swprintf(buf,L"%s%d",L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again? ",a); 
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL, buf,
        (LPCTSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1
    );
   return msgboxID;
}

int main()
{
   DisplayResourceNAMessageBox(); 
}
```

Вариант с `wstring`:

```
#define  UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

int a = 10;
int DisplayResourceNAMessageBox()
{
    std::wstring buf = L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again? "
                     + std::to_wstring(a);
    int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL, buf.c_str(),
        (LPCTSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1
    );
   return msgboxID;
}

int main()
{
   DisplayResourceNAMessageBox(); 
}
```

Comment: swprintf требует размера вроде как

Comment: @KoVadim В VС++ необязательно. Он немного ругается, но работает :)

Comment: ага, компилироваться оно компилируется, а работать....

Comment: @KoVadim  Ну я же скомпилировал и запустил... VC++ 2019 Как вам доказать? Прислать видео? :) Чтоб не было вопросов - подправил ответ.

Comment: ага, мсдн надо читатть:) https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l?view=msvc-160 и читаем, там написано без указания размера можно, это для особых случаев. Но  лучше так не  делать

Comment: Ну, два минуса - это уже что-то... Только вот что именно? Поясните, что не так написано в ответе?

Comment: Вы не единственный, кто жалуется ))

Answer (score 0):

где то так

```
wchar_t buff[1024];
swprintf(buff, 1024, L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again? a = %d", a);

int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCTSTR)buff,
        (LPCTSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1
    );
```